# Why WPF app takes a few minutes to complete closing?

Tags: wpf, powershell

Here's a quite simple code but I found a weird behaviour when closing the app from task bar (right-click icon -> `Close window`). Could somebody explain why it behaves like the following?

a) if window is minimized the app takes a few minutes to complete closing.

b) if window is not minimized app closes immediately.

c) if window is minimized but the 2 commented lines are uncommented app closes immediately.

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

[xml]$xaml = @'
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    >
</Window>
'@
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$window.add_Closing({
    # $window.WindowState = "Normal"
    # $window.Hide()
    Write-Host "Here will everytime be passed immediately."
})
$window.ShowDialog() > $null
Write-Host "Here takes time to be passed when minimized."
```

#### Environment

- Windows 10 Home (10.0.18363)
- PowerShell 5.1.18362.752

## Updated 08/06/2020

Added two `Write-Host` statement. Both will be passed immediately in case of b) and c) but won't in case of a).

Comment: more details? are you running it in ISE or VSCode? For me its closing immediately in both ISE and VS code as well

Comment: I'm running on VS Code and PowerShell console and they result the same.